# C++ template functions to partially implement Python numpy ndarray limited to 1d and 2d

Tags: c++, matrix, template

I just read a book on creating a neural network. The book uses Python. I wanted to port this to C++. In order to do that I had to create template functions to implement some of the `numpy` matrix functions.  The template functions that I created attempt to be portable (work on any C++), size independent and type independent (though I am using `double`s). Instead of arrays it uses nested `std::vector`s.
I was wondering if using `size_t` is okay. The reason for it is to avoid a comparison of an unsigned and signed number.

**Note**: The template function `CreateNormalized` does a lame attempt to emulate `numpy.random.normal(0.0, pow(self.inodes, -0.5), (self.hnodes, self.inodes))`. This version makes no attempt at normal distribution but I think this ok since it is only creating random number within a given range.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>

// template class to create a 2D vector
// given rows, cols and an a initial value
template <class T, class T2>
std::vector <std::vector<T>> CreateVector(T2 rows, T2 cols, T init)
{
    std::vector <std::vector<T>> c(rows, std::vector<T>(cols, init));
    return  c;
}

// template class to create a 2D square vector
// given size and an a initial value
template <class T, class T2>
std::vector <std::vector<T>> CreateVector(T2 size, T init)
{
    std::vector <std::vector<T>> c(size, std::vector<T>(size, init));
    return  c;
}

// template class to assign a 1D vector to a 2D vector
template <class T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>>To2D(const std::vector<T>& a)
{
    auto out = CreateVector((a.size() + 1) - a.size(), a.size(), T(0));
    auto cols = a.size();
    for (size_t col = 0; col < cols; ++col)
    {
        out[0][col] = a[col];
    }
    return out;
}

// template class to Transpose a 2D vector
//
//  1  2  3      1  4
//  4  5  6      2  5
//               3  6
// 
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose
template <class T>
std::vector <std::vector<T>> Transpose(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& a)
{
    auto rows = a.size();
    auto cols = a[0].size();

    auto out = CreateVector(cols, rows, T(0));
    for (size_t row = 0;  row < rows;  ++row)
    {
        for (size_t col = 0; col < cols; ++col)
        {
            out[col][row] = a[row][col];
        }
    }
    return out;
}

// template class to create a random 2D vector with a scale average
template <class T, class T2> 
std::vector <std::vector<T>> CreateNormalized(T loc, T scale, T2 rows, T2 cols)
{
    auto a1 = scale / 2.0;
    auto a2 = loc - a1;

    auto out = CreateVector(rows, cols, loc);
    for (T2 row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
    {
        for (T2 col = 0; col < cols; ++col)
        {
            auto x = ((double(rand()) / RAND_MAX) * scale) + a2;
            out[row][col] = x;
        }
    }
    return out;
}

// template class to subtract a 2D vector from a constant
template <class T>
std::vector <std::vector<T>> Subtract(const T n, const std::vector<std::vector<T>> &a)
{
    auto rows = a.size();
    auto cols = a[0].size();

    auto out = CreateVector(rows, cols, T(0));
    for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
    {
        for (size_t col = 0; col < cols; ++col)
        {
            out[row][col] = n - a[row][col];
        }
    }
    return out;
}

// template class to subtract a 2D vector from another 2D vector
template <class T>
std::vector <std::vector<T>> Subtract(const std::vector<std::vector<T>> &a, const std::vector<std::vector<T>> &b)
{
    auto rows = a.size();
    auto cols = a[0].size();

    auto out = CreateVector(rows, cols, T(0));
    for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
    {
        for (size_t col = 0; col < cols; ++col)
        {
            out[row][col] = a[row][col] - b[row][col];
        }
    }
    return out;
}

// template class to add a 2D vector to another 2D vector
template <class T>
std::vector <std::vector<T>> Add(const std::vector<std::vector<T>> &a, const std::vector<std::vector<T>> &b)
{
    auto arows = a.size();
    auto acols = a[0].size();
    auto brows = b.size();
    auto bcols = b[0].size();

    auto rows = arows + brows;
    auto cols = std::max(acols, bcols);

    auto out = CreateVector(rows, cols, T(0));
    for (size_t row = arows - arows; row < arows; ++row)
    {
        for (size_t col = acols - acols; col < acols; ++col)
        {
            out[row][col] = a[row][col];
        }
    }

    size_t r = 0;
    for (auto row = arows; row < rows; ++row, ++r)
    {
        for (auto col = bcols - bcols; col < bcols; ++col)
        {
            out[row][col] = b[r][col];
        }
    }
    return out;
}

// Multiply 2D vector A by single value B returning the result vector
template <class T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> Multiply(const T &n, const std::vector<std::vector<T>> &a)
{
    auto rows = a.size();
    auto cols = a[0].size();

    auto out = CreateVector(rows, cols, T(0));
    for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
    {
        for (size_t col = 0; col < cols; ++col)
        {
            out[row][col] = n * a[row][col];
        }
    }
    return out;
}

// Multiply 2D vector A by 2D vector B returning the result vector AB
// based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication
//
//        a b c         j k l
//   A =  d e f    B =  m n o
//        g h i         p q r
//
//       (a*j + b*m + c*p) (a*k + b*n + c*q) (a*l + b*o + c*r)
//  AB = (d*j + e*m + f*p) (d*k + e*n + f*q) (d*l + e*o + f*r)
//       (g*j + q*m + r*p) (g*k + h*n + i*q) (g*l + h*o + i*r)
//
template <class T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> Multiply(const std::vector<std::vector<T>> &a, const std::vector<std::vector<T>> &b)
{
    const auto n = a.size();     // a rows
    const auto m = a[0].size();  // a cols
    const auto p = b[0].size();  // b cols

    // create the result vector initilized with 0
    std::vector <std::vector<T>> c(n, std::vector<T>(p, T(0)));

    for (size_t row = 0; row < p; ++row)
    {
        for (size_t column = 0; column < m; ++column)
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            {
                c[i][row] += a[i][column] * b[column][row];
            }
        }
    }
    return c;
}

// template class to subtract a 2D vector from a constant
template <class T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> operator-(const T n, const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& b)
{
    auto c = Subtract(n, b);
    return c;
}

// template class for adding a 2D matrix to another 2D matrix
template <class T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> operator+=(std::vector<std::vector<T>>& a, const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& b)
{
    auto arows = a.size();
    auto acols = a[0].size();
    auto brows = b.size();
    auto bcols = b[0].size();

    auto rows = arows + brows;
    auto cols = std::max(acols, bcols);

    auto r = 0;
    for (auto row = arows; row < rows; ++row, ++r)
    {
        std::vector<T> rr(bcols);
        for (auto col = bcols - bcols; col < bcols; ++col)
        {
            rr[col] = b[r][col];
        }
        a.push_back(rr);
    }
    return a;
}

// template class opererator to add a 2D vector to another 2D vector
template <class T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> operator+(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& a, const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& b)
{
    auto c = Add(a, b);
    return c;
}

// template class opererator to subtract a 2D vector from another 2D vector
template <class T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> operator-(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& a, const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& b)
{
    auto c = Subtract(a, b);
    return c;
}

// template class opererator to multiply a 2D vector with another 2D vector
template <class T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> operator*(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& a, const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& b)
{
    auto c = Multiply(a, b);
    return c;
}

// template class opererator to multiply a 2D vector with const
template <class T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> operator*(const T & n, const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& a)
{
    auto c = Multiply(n, a);
    return c;
}

// Function to get cofactor of a[p][q] in b[][]
template <class T,  class T2>
void GetCofactor(std::vector<std::vector<T>> &a, std::vector<std::vector<T>> &b, T2 p, T2 q, T2 n)
{
    T2 i = 0;
    T2 j = 0;

    // Looping for each element of the matrix
    for (T2 row = 0; row < n; ++row)
    {
        for (T2 col = 0; col < n; ++col)
        {
            //  Copying into temporary matrix only those element
            //  which are not in given row and column
            if (row != p && col != q)
            {
                b[i][j++] = a[row][col];

                // Row is filled, so increase row index and
                // reset col index
                if (j == n - 1)
                {
                    j = 0;
                    ++i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Recursive function for finding determinant of matrix.
template <class T, class T2>
T Determinant(std::vector<std::vector<T>> &a, T2 n)
{
    T d = 0; // Initialize result

    //  Base case : if matrix contains single element
    if (n == 1)
        return a[0][0];

    auto temp = CreateVector(n, d);
    auto sign = 1;  // To store sign multiplier

    // Iterate for each element of first row
    for (T2 f = 0; f < n;  ++f)
    {
        // Getting Cofactor of A[0][f]
        GetCofactor(a, temp, T2(0), f, n);
        d += sign * a[0][f] * Determinant(temp, n - 1);

        // terms are to be added with alternate sign
        sign = -sign;
    }
    return d;
}

// Function to get adjoint of A[N][N] in adj[N][N].
template <class T, class T2>
void Adjoint(std::vector<std::vector<T>> &a, std::vector<std::vector<T>> &adj, T2 n)
{
    if (n == 1)
    {
        adj[0][0] = T(1);
        return;
    }

    // b is used to store cofactors of A[][]
    auto sign = 1;
    auto temp = CreateVector(n, T(0));

    for (T2 row = 0; row<n; ++row)
    {
        for (T2 column = 0; column < n; ++column)
        {
            // Get cofactor of A[i][j]
            GetCofactor(a, temp, row, column, n);

            // sign of adj[j][i] positive if sum of row
            // and column indexes is even.
            sign = ((row + column) % 2 == 0) ? 1 : -1;

            // Interchanging rows and columns to get the
            // transpose of the cofactor matrix
            adj[column][row] = (sign)*(Determinant(temp, n - 1));
        }
    }
}

// template class to calculate and store inverse, returns false if
// matrix is singular
template <class T>
bool Inverse(std::vector<std::vector<T>> &a, std::vector<std::vector<T>> &inverse)
{
    const auto n = a.size();

    // Find determinant of A[][]
    auto det = Determinant(a, n);
    if (det == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Singular matrix, can't find its inverse";
        return false;
    }

    // Find adjoint
    auto adj = CreateVector(n, det);
    Adjoint(a, adj, n);

    // Find Inverse using formula "inverse(A) = adj(A)/det(A)"
    for (size_t i =0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            inverse[i][j] = adj[i][j] / det;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// template class opererator to get the inverse of a 2D vector
template <class T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> operator~(std::vector<std::vector<T>>& a)
{
    auto inv = CreateVector(a.size(), T(0));  // To store inverse of A[][]
    auto ok = Inverse(a, inv);
    return inv;
}

// template class to print a 2D vector
template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<std::vector<T>> &a)
{
    const auto precision = 6;
    const auto mantisa = 4;
    const auto spacing = 2;

    const auto n = a.size();     // a rows
    const auto m = a[0].size();  // a cols

    auto isInt = std::is_integral<T>::value;

    os.setf(std::ios::fixed, std::ios::floatfield);
    os.precision(precision);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < m; ++j)
        {
            if (isInt)
                os << std::setw(8) << a[i][j];
            else
                os << std::setw(precision + mantisa + spacing) << a[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return os;
}
```

for completeness I am adding Gauss elimination method for matrix

```
template <class T>
bool  MatrixInversion(std::vector<std::vector<T>> &a, std::vector<std::vector<T>>&aInverse)
{
    auto n = a.size();

    // A = input matrix (n x n) copied to ac
    // n = dimension of A 
    // AInverse = inverted matrix (n x n)
    // This function inverts a matrix based on the Gauss Jordan method.
    // The function returns 1 on success, 0 on failure.
    size_t icol, irow;
    T det, factor;

    auto ac = CreateVector(n, T(0));
    det = 1;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            aInverse[i][j] = 0;
            ac[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
        aInverse[i][i] = 1;
    }

    // The current pivot row is iPass.  
    // For each pass, first find the maximum element in the pivot column.
    for (size_t iPass = 0; iPass < n; iPass++)
    {
        auto imx = iPass;
        for (irow = iPass; irow < n; irow++)
        {
            if (fabs(ac[irow][iPass]) > fabs(ac[imx][iPass])) imx = irow;
        }
        // Interchange the elements of row iPass and row imx in both A and AInverse.
        if (imx != iPass)
        {
            for (icol = 0; icol < n; icol++)
            {
                T temp = aInverse[iPass][icol];
                aInverse[iPass][icol] = aInverse[imx][icol];
                aInverse[imx][icol] = temp;

                if (icol >= iPass)
                {
                    temp = ac[iPass][icol];
                    ac[iPass][icol] = ac[imx][icol];
                    ac[imx][icol] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        // The current pivot is now A[iPass][iPass].
        // The determinant is the product of the pivot elements.
        T pivot = ac[iPass][iPass];
        det = det * pivot;
        if (det == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (icol = 0; icol < n; icol++)
        {
            // Normalize the pivot row by dividing by the pivot element.
            aInverse[iPass][icol] = aInverse[iPass][icol] / pivot;
            if (icol >= iPass) ac[iPass][icol] = ac[iPass][icol] / pivot;
        }

        for (irow = 0; irow < n; irow++)
            // Add a multiple of the pivot row to each row.  The multiple factor 
            // is chosen so that the element of A on the pivot column is 0.
        {
            if (irow != iPass) factor = ac[irow][iPass];
            for (icol = 0; icol < n; icol++)
            {
                if (irow != iPass)
                {
                    aInverse[irow][icol] -= factor * aInverse[iPass][icol];
                    ac[irow][icol] -= factor * ac[iPass][icol];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use someone else's library instead of rolling your own, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380371/what-are-the-most-widely-used-c-vector-matrix-math-linear-algebra-libraries-a) and [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries#C.2B.2B) discuss possible libraries.

- Many older C++ compilers will not allow consecutive `>>` to close out the template, as it will be mistaken for the right-shift operator by the parser. You'll need to put a space between them.
- If you need your code to work on "original" C++ (pre-C++0x) you should use a `typedef` inside your class for the matrix, rather than repeating `std::vector<std::vector<T> >` all over the place. If you can guarantee that it will only be used by C++0x users, you should use `using Matrix = std::vector<std::vector<T>>;` as this preserves the templating.
- Your `Subtract()` routine (and thus your `operator-`) will fail if the two matrices are not the same dimensions.
- It looks like your `Add()` routine, despite what the comment would suggest, is performing the same task as numpy's `vstack()`. Why not call it that?
- I don't understand this idiom `for (size_t row = arows - arows; row < arows; ++row)` at all. Why subtract `arows` from itself?
- Your `Multiply()` (and thus your `operator*`) will fail if the two matrices are not compatible.
- Your `+=` operator will fail of the two matrices are not the same dimensions.
- I strongly question your overloading of the `+` operator to perform `vstack()`, especially when you use the `-` operator for ordinary subtraction, and the `+=` operator for ordinary addition.
- It is counterproductive to create a temporary variable in all your operator arithmetic routines. This will cause multiple unnecessary copies.
- Your `Determinant()` function uses the naive grade-school algorithm to calculate. This is unnecessarily slow (runtime is proportional to the cube of the element count) and very susceptible to round-off error. Please look into other methods of calculating the determinant.
- Your `Inverse()` function (and thus your `operator~`) uses the naive grade-school algorithm. It inherits the slowness and numerical instability from `Determinant()`. But it's worse since you'll be post-multiplying. Please don't do this -- use a better algorithm like LU decomposition.
- I don't see the random function anywhere.

Comment: Actually, 'using' is *preferred* to 'typedef' in this context, in C++0x.

Comment: Well OP says it's supposed to "work on any C++", which in my mind suggests that only ISO/IEC 14882:1998 is available...

Comment: I think it’s worth mentioning as an aside, since future readers that don’t see that caveat may pick up a bad recommendation for C++0x.

Comment: @JNS, shouldn't we call it C++11 now? Although C++2a is more or less new, C++0x have been here for more than a decade.

Comment: @Incomputable C++0x refers to the latest standard, being C++17.

Comment: @JNS, the only alias I heard for C++17 is C++1z. Clang and gcc use C++1z. Where did you heard that from?

Comment: @Incomputable Yes sorry, typo on my part, I meant 1z.

Comment: @JNS, no problems. Sorry if I was too confrontational.

Comment: @JNS I added it, did I get it right?

Comment: @Snowbody Yep, perfect.

Comment: For readers of this, I used the first method that I found to implement matrix inversion which is apparently inefficient. I thank all of you for the feedback.

Comment: Actually, Paul, I checked out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix and the adjugate method is actually quite efficient for small matrices. You were right the first time. However it is numerically unstable.

Comment: @Snowbody I implemented the Gaussian elimination method. In 5 seconds adjunct method executed 2,726 times,  Gaussian  executed 31,000 times. gaussian   has a huge advantage.

Comment: @PaulBaxter did you test the performance of adjunct method with the better algorithm for determinant?

Comment: @Snowbody I have not yet. I have been looking for a better algorithm unsuccessfully.

Comment: @PaulBaxter https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Calculation says that most of the time methods are used that don't involve calculating the determinant